# How to reshape based on time?

Tags: r, reshape

I have a time series data:

```
  date value
12  2016-08-05   854
13  2016-07-29  1065
14  2016-07-22   878
15  2016-07-15  1145
16  2016-07-08   735
17  2016-07-01   730
18  2016-06-24   726
19  2016-06-17  1011
20  2016-06-10  1019
```

What I want is a matrix of monthly data:

```
Jan Feb March ... (more months)
123 222 555
234 333 555
456 444 666
```

How do I reshape the input data to the desired output? I believe `reshape` function may be helpful, but not sure how.

Answer (score 2):

The following should also work:

```
df <- read.table(text='date value
                 12  2016-08-05   854
                 13  2016-07-29  1065
                 14  2016-07-22   878
                 15  2016-07-15  1145
                 16  2016-07-08   735
                 17  2016-07-01   730
                 18  2016-06-24   726
                 19  2016-06-17  1011
                 20  2016-06-10  1019
                 21  2015-06-01  225', header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)
df$month <- format(df$date, '%b')
df$year <- format(df$date, '%Y')
df <- df[c('year', 'month',  'value')]
df %>% group_by(month, year) %>% summarise(value=sum(value)) %>% spread(month, value)

#  year   Aug   Jul   Jun
#  (chr) (int) (int) (int)
#1  2015    NA    NA   225
#2  2016   854  4553  2756
```

Answer (score 1):

We create the 'Month' column by converting the 'Date' to `Date` class, `format` it to extract the 'Month', convert it to `factor` with `levels` specified as `month.abb` and then `dcast` it to 'wide' format

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Month := factor(format(as.Date(date), "%b"), levels = month.abb)]
dcast(df1, rowid(Month)~Month, value.var = "value", drop = FALSE, fill = 0)
```

---

Or we can do this `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
 df1 %>% 
    group_by(Month = factor(month.abb[month(date)], levels = month.abb))  %>%
    mutate(ind = row_number()) %>% 
    spread(Month, value, drop = FALSE, fill=0)
```